# Ruby - how to set the element value for an array of array element

Tags: ruby

If I have an array with five empty arrays inside of it i.e.

```
`5_empty_arrays = [[], [], [], [], []]`
```

how would I insert a name into the 1st array of the overall array i.e.

```
`[["Dean"], [], [], [], []]`
```

?

I can currently get

```
`5_empty_arrays.insert[0, "Dean"]`

`[["Dean"], [], [], [], [], []]`
```

but that adds an extra array it doesn't insert into the 1st array.

**I followed the advice of Steen slag and made the changes to my existing code but I now get "Dean" printed in every element. However, when I manually create the array of arrays as Steen slag did it works as predicted. Any idea? Thanks!**

```
number_of_groups = 5

array = []
array = array.push([])* number_of_groups
array[0] << "Dean"
p array

=> [["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"]]
```

Comment: `5_empty_arrays` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: As in it's confusing?

Comment: Ruby variable names can't start with a number.

Comment: Regarding `[["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"], ["Dean"]]`, I think it's not pushing a new array into the original array 5 times, it's pushing one array into the original array and then duplicating the references to the one pushed in array 4 times; so `array[0]`, `array[1]` `array[2]` etc. all reference the same array.

Comment: Maybe try `array = (1..number_of_groups).to_a.map { |n| [] }` or `array = Array.new(number_of_groups){ |i| [] }` instead.

Comment: Cheers for this!

Comment: To define array of empty arrays: `Array.new(5) { [] }`

Answer (score 2):

```
five_empty_arrays = [[], [], [], [], []]
five_empty_arrays[0] << "Dean"
five_empty_arrays[0] << "John"

p five_empty_arrays # => [["Dean", "John"], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

You were inserting an element (hence the new array element) but you just want to set it

```
irb

> arrays = [[],[],[],[],[]]
=> [[], [], [], [], []]

irb> arrays[0][0]='a'
=> "a"

irb> arrays
=> [["a"], [], [], [], []]
```

To preserve any existing values you could use:

```
> arrays[0][0]='a'
=> "a"
    
> arrays
=> [["a"], [], [], [], []]
    
> existing = arrays[0][0]
=> "a"
    
> newbie = [existing, 'newnew']
=> ["a", "newnew"]
    
> arrays[0] = newbie
=> ["a", "newnew"]
    
> arrays
=> [["a", "newnew"], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Thanks! But what If I wanted to add another string into arrays[0] and I didn't know how many elements were inside. For example ...  => [["a", "b", "Dean"], [], [], [], []]

Comment: ok, that is a somewhat different question

Comment: Added code that would preserve the existing value

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to select the first inner array first. You could do this with `5_empty_arrays[0]` or at().

e.g.

```
> five_empty_arrays = [['a', 'b'], [], [], [], []]
=> [["a", "b"], [], [], [], []]
> five_empty_arrays[0].insert(0, "Dean")
=> ["Dean", "a", "b"]
> five_empty_arrays
=> [["Dean", "a", "b"], [], [], [], []]
```

If you wanted to add to the end of the inner array you could use push() instead of insert().

```
> five_empty_arrays = [['a', 'b'], [], [], [], []]
=> [["a", "b"], [], [], [], []]
> five_empty_arrays[0].push("Dean")
=> ["a", "b", "Dean"]
> five_empty_arrays
=> [["a", "b", "Dean"], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply doing a

```
array[0].unshift 'Dean'
```

? This would work even if array[0] is a non-empty array.